# How to work with virtual key board in android(catch event on keys which display Toast after press)

Tags: android

i am doing R&D on virtual key board (How to catch key event),but no more success found
i got only few things about virtual key board

we need to implements

`onKeyboradActionListener`

```
/* and these override methode*/

public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onRelease(int primaryCode) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

if any one know this share his knowledge

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this might help, but I thought it might be related to your question.

[Creating an Input Method](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/creating-input-method.html)

Answer (score 0):

The below given code might help you...

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You have Clicked the button I", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this is for virtual key board or just for Hard key Board

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You Clike MenuButto", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }else 
    {
        return false;
    }       
}
```